# wave equation with only initial partial x condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the outgoing signal problem, 
$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx}, x>0$

$u_x(0,t) = s(t) $

Where $s(t)$ is a known signal.  Hint: look for a right-traveling wave.

Here is what I have done:

$u(t,x) = p(x-ct) + q(x+ct)$

$u_x(t,x) = p'(x-ct) + q'(x+ct)$

$u(t,0) = p(-ct) + q(ct)$

Let $S'(t) = s(t)$

$u_x(t,0) = p'(-ct) + q'(ct) = S'(t)$

$u(0,t) = p(-ct) + q(ct)$

+

$c * \bigg( S(t) = -\frac{1}{c}p(-ct) + \frac{1}{c}q(ct) \bigg)$

$=$

$u(0,t) + cS(t) = 2q(ct)$

$\frac{1}{2} u(0,t) + \frac{1}{2c}S(t) = q(ct)$

But from here I am not sure what to do? I tried writing out what $q(x+ct)$ and $p(x-ct)$ would be but then I would just get $u=0$ as follows,

$q(x+ct) = \frac{1}{2} u(0, \frac{x+ct}{c}) + \frac{1}{2c}S(\frac{x+ct}{c})$

$p(x-ct) = -\frac{1}{2} u(0, \frac{-(x+ct)}{-c}) - \frac{1}{2c}S(\frac{-(x+ct)}{-c})$

The hint does say look for right traveling waves so maybe I only want to use $q$? I am not sure how to proceed.